# how to get the "value" using xpath and place into array?

Tags: xpath, arraylist

how do i get the value "3" using xpath? i have tried this but i was till not able to get the value "3" the result says path not found. and also is my arraylist correct?

```
                List4 = new ArrayList<String>();
                driver.findElement(By
                        .xpath(".//*[@id='fileRef']/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/div/span/@value"));
                List4.add("@value");
                System.out.println(List4);



<tr class="rowOdd">
<td style="width:25">
<div id="uniform-fileRefSysId_3" class="radio">
<span>
<input id="fileRefSysId_3" type="radio" value="3" onclick="javascript:setFileRef(this.id);" name="fileRef"/>
</span>
</div>
<input id="fileRefTitle_3" type="hidden" value="CLT-02"/>
<input id="fileRefNo_3" type="hidden" value="CLT-02"/>
</td>
<td>Consultant</td>
<td>CLT-02</td>
<td>CLT-02</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

The xpath you are looking for is `.//*[@name='fileRef']/@value`. You'll also need to tell `driver` to put the result into your list somehow (read the manual!).

Comment: i have try out your method but the error return is this. the given selector .//*[@name='fileRef']/@value is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:
InvalidSelectorError: The result of the xpath expression ".//*[@name='fileRef']/@value" is: [object XrayWrapper [object Attr]]. It should be an element.

Comment: @sssheng the result of that xpath is `3`. That is a value, not an element. Use a different method of your driver that accepts values or extract the value from the input element yourself.

Comment: bro do you have any solution to it?